# Section layer in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

What is a good way to section the canvas and/or a layer in Adobe Illustrator?

I have a blank white canvas at the moment, and I'd like to draw a jagged line across the middle from the left end of the canvas to the right. Then I want to split the canvas across this division so that I can color the top half as a sky and the bottom half as a terrain.

I tried do this by creating a path with the pen tool, and I was able to get things so that the bottom half was its own shape, but I can't seem to figure out how to select the complement of the bottom half within the canvas.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Artboards (or canvases) are not drawable objects. That is to say, you can't fill them with color or otherwise alter them the same way you would an object.

Think of the artboard/canvas in Illustrator as your desk... things just sit on top of it, but you don't actually alter it. It's because of this fundamental difference that they are generally referred to as "artboards" which is vastly different than a "canvas" in Photoshop.

Draw a rectangle, then divide it and color the pieces.

Comment: Thanks, so once I draw the rectangle, how would I section it using an arbitrary path as a divider?

Comment: Try going through some basic tutorials to learn how the basic things in Illustrator work: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/tutorials.html